# Why does Graphics2d.drawImage throw a NullPointerException?

Tags: java, kotlin, printing, awt

I'm writing an application that uses a printer (like inkjet, laser, etc) and I'm using a `Printable` to print my page. `drawImage` throws an NPE, but the image displays correctly. I've tested this with Temurin 17.0.5 and Oracle OpenJDK 19.0.1.

Additional information:
This is happening on Ubuntu 22.04 and I haven't tested it on any other platforms. The NPE happens after `drawImage` returns typically. If I have the program block until `observer` is notified, the NPE remains.

Exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.awt.image.ImageConsumer.setColorModel(java.awt.image.ColorModel)" because "this.theConsumer" is null
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.image.OffScreenImageSource.sendPixels(OffScreenImageSource.java:171)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.image.OffScreenImageSource.produce(OffScreenImageSource.java:187)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.image.OffScreenImageSource.addConsumer(OffScreenImageSource.java:66)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.image.OffScreenImageSource.startProduction(OffScreenImageSource.java:80)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.image.FilteredImageSource.startProduction(FilteredImageSource.java:184)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.image.ImageRepresentation.startProduction(ImageRepresentation.java:732)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.image.ToolkitImage.addWatcher(ToolkitImage.java:221)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.image.ToolkitImage.getHeight(ToolkitImage.java:142)
    at java.desktop/sun.print.PeekGraphics$ImageWaiter.waitForDimensions(PeekGraphics.java:1888)
    at java.desktop/sun.print.PeekGraphics$ImageWaiter.<init>(PeekGraphics.java:1876)
    at java.desktop/sun.print.PeekGraphics.drawImage(PeekGraphics.java:955)
    ... the rest is my code
```

My code is Kotlin and something like:

```kotlin
class MyPrintable : Printable {
    override fun print(graphics: Graphics, pageFormat: PageFormat, pageIndex: Int): Int {
        if (pageIndex > 0) {
            return NO_SUCH_PAGE
        }
        val g2d = graphics as Graphics2D

        drawString(...)
        drawString(...)

        val image1: BufferedImage = loadImage1()
        // The following line throws an NPE asynchronously
        drawImage(image1.getScaledInstance(width, height, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH), x, y, null)

        val image2: BufferedImage = loadImage2()
        drawImage(image1.getScaledInstance(width, height, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH), x2, y2, null)

        return PAGE_EXISTS
    }
}
```

It seems to only throw an exception on the first `drawImage` despite them being on basically the same code path.

Comment: I would guess it is because you passed `null` as the last argument to `drawImage`.

Comment: I would've guess that too, but it's not the problem. `theConsumer` is an `ImageConsumer`, the last parameter of `drawImage` is an `ImageObserver`. Adding an observer there doesn't prevent the NPE

Comment: This is a question about Java libraries. My code is written in Kotlin, but there's nothing related to Kotlin in the question, I just didn't feel like translating my code to Java.

Comment: `loadImage1` loads the image asynchroneously and evidently not completely when starting to draw. Load it synchroneously, perhaps something for ImageIO.

Comment: That's it! loadImage was calling `getScaledInstance`. I thought `drawImage` was supposed to work asynchronously in that case. Replacing `getScaledIntance` with a synchronous version fixes the NPE.